# How to update data from Modbus RTU device to Form through C#

Tags: c#, modbus

I want to update value reading from register Modbus device then display on Windows Forms every seconds Here is that code I made by C#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RTU2();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error");
        }

    //    Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public  void RTU2()
    {

        using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM7"))
        {

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
            {

                // configure serial port
                port.BaudRate = 19200;
                port.DataBits = 8;
                port.Parity = Parity.None;
                port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                port.Open();
                while (true)
                {
                    {
                        // create modbus master
                        ModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);

                        byte slaveId = 1;
                        int startua1 = int.Parse(txtUA1.Text.Trim(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                        ushort startAddressua1 = (ushort)startua1;

                        // read large value in two 16 bit chunks and perform conversion
                        Thread.Sleep(100); // Delay 100ms
                        ushort[] registersua = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddressua1, 2);
                      
              

                        float UAV = (float)(decimal)valueua / 100000;
                      
                        //DISPLAY VALUE ON FORM
                        UA.Text = UAV.ToString("###,###.00");//'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'UA' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
                      

                        Thread.Sleep(2000); // Delay 20ms
                    }
                }

            }));

        }
```

However,It was error like this  . [image]

Please help me how should I edit that code to running well, Thank you

Comment: It seems `UA` is a control, and you're trying to modify `UA.Text` in a non-UI thread in `ThreadPool`. I'll suggest you save in a member variable and Update the value to `UA.Text` in a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`'s `Tick` event.

Comment: I post an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `UA` is a control, and you're trying to modify `UA.Text` in a non-UI thread in `ThreadPool`.

To Achieve that, save your value in `m_szUAV` and update `m_szUAV` to UA.Text in a System.Windows.Forms.Timer's Tick event.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
public Form1()
{
    // Constructor's original code 
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initial your timer
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 50;
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Enable = true;
}

string m_szUAV = string.Empty;

private void Timer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    UA.Text = m_szUAV;
}

public  void RTU2()
{

    using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM7"))
    {

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
        {

            // configure serial port
            port.BaudRate = 19200;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.Open();
            while (true)
            {
                {
                    // create modbus master
                    ModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);

                    byte slaveId = 1;
                    int startua1 = int.Parse(txtUA1.Text.Trim(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    ushort startAddressua1 = (ushort)startua1;

                    // read large value in two 16 bit chunks and perform conversion
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // Delay 100ms
                    ushort[] registersua = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddressua1, 2);

                    float UAV = (float)(decimal)valueua / 100000;

                    // Save value to private member
                    m_szUAV = UAV.ToString("###,###.00");

                    Thread.Sleep(2000); // Delay
                }
            }

        }));

    }
```

Comment: Thank you . Is this gonna remove Thread Pool and Thread Sleep, Loop inside RTU2() method  ? Because you are using System.Windows.Forms.Timer() to refresh data every milliseconds .

Comment: @ELIP You still has to use `ThreadPool` for background reading RTU value to `m_zUAV`. Using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer()` is just for updating the UI without `Invoke`.

Comment: Though `ThreadPool` with a `while(true)` is not a good way to implement a routine if you need to keep. At least set a a stop flag for it. Eg: `while(stop == false)`

Comment: @ELIP Check my edited answer, it should be more clear.

Comment: I tried code from your answer. It doesn't display value on textbox. Even thought Value is passed in UAV variable inside method RTU2() method. It seems that value is not updated or refreshed while real value changed over time

Comment: Is it ok if I create method storing value to database ( INSERT query) inside RTU2 () method right below line  float UAV = (float)(decimal)valueua / 100000;

Comment: @ELIP Saveing into database is a way but would be overkill rather than saving into a string. All you need is storing this data and let UI update it. So `timer.Enable = true` is still required for update.

Comment: Value was displayed on TextBox. However It was not refresh every second as Timer or Thread set. It show only value once button clicked and keep that value till button off

Comment: @ELIP is `Timer_Tick` actually fired? Put a breakpoint to check it. Make sure `timer.Enable=true;` is set.

Comment: I've mistaken RTU2() method. I should be static void . Then It worked for me. Anyway thank you